# Operator= - Structure in class (SingleLinkedList)

Tags: c++, class, structure

I need to make an opertor= for my class Sequene which keep structure called element in private part. The problem is - how can I use that structure from class x in such function?

```
    template<typename Key, typename Info>
    void Sequence<Key,Info>::operator=(const Sequence &x)
    {
        element *ptr=head;
        while(ptr)//deallocating memory
        {
            head=ptr->next;
            delete[] ptr;
            ptr=head;
        }
        x.element *ptr2;// <- it doesn't work - how can I make a ptr for structure of class x here?
// rest of code 
.
.
.
//



    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what precisely the problem is. However, there are two big problems anyway: 1.) Your `operator=` should return a reference to `*this`, because that's often expected by other code, especially various standard containers. 2.) The copy assignment `operator=` should almost always be implemented using the Copy & Swap idiom. And of course, you shouldn't have to do all of this in the first place. Just use a standard container like `std::vector` or `std::map`.

Comment: Sorry that is my first post. Anyway the problem is I really can't make a pointer to element of x class. I really don't know how to do it. Well it's a part of project for laboratories for my studies and my supervisor said we cant use standard libraries for list etc. :C

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not a class, it's (a reference to) an object.

If you want to access its `head` member, you would write `x.head`.
This member has the type `element*`, so you would declare a variable

```
element* ptr2 = x.head;
```

(I would recommend that you review the earlier parts of your course, in particular the introduction to structures.)